# The DirectoryIndex and DocumentRoot in apache 2

Tags: 18.04, server, apache2, webserver, websites

I have `/var/www/html/moodle` as my website directory. When in `mysite.conf` the settings are as follows:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

mysite.com gives an `Index of/` page since there is only apache's `index.html` in the default location as index file.
How can I make mysite.com load `/var/www/html/moodle/index.php`?

I tried giving in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`

```
DirectoryIndex /moodle/index.php
```

With this mysite.com loads the moodle homepage, but other`index` pages inside moodle are not loading.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by changing the line

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /moodle/index.php
```

in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`.

**Source :**
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html